# Get undefined for receiving a signal with parameter from C++ in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-signals

I am trying to receive a signal with parameter in QML from C++ QObject class.
The signal looks be triggered but parameter got undefined:

myclass.h

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~MyClass();

    Q_INVOKABLE void monitorResult();

signals:
    void resultChanged(QString newResult);
}
```

myclass.cpp

```cpp
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::monitorResult()
{
    QString str = "test";
    
    emit resultChanged(str);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("MyClass", new MyClass());

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/my.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
)
```

QML

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: screen
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 93
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    title: qsTr("screen")
    color: "transparent"

    Image {
        id: homeScreen_footer_image
        y: 70
        width: 1920
        height: 93
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        opacity: 1
        source: "images/12_Footer.png"

        Timer {
            interval: 250
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: MyClass.monitorResult()
        }

        Connections {
            target: MyClass

            function onResultChanged(result) {
                console.log("onResultChanged triggerred")
                console.log("result: " + result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get below message on QML stating:

> qml: onResultChanged triggerred
> qml: newGestureResult: undefined

Can someone help me?

Appreciate in advance.

I try to find solution on Qt documentation and stackoverflow but still no idea what happened.

Comment: I would change `MyClass` to `myClass`, There is [agreement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute) for the `id` name case. In this case it is not really `id` but worth to try. Also `resultChanged(QString newResult)` probably should be `resultChanged(const QString& newResult)`

Comment: @folibis Thanks for your quick reply. I tried but did not works.

Comment: I think you have wrong syntax in Connections section.
Try this 
```Conneticions { target: MyClass onResultChanged: { console.log(result) }}```

Comment: This is the correct remark of @Mike. Since you did not specify the version of `Qt` that you are using, I assumed it was `Qt6`, but there was a significant change in the syntax of `Connections` while switching from `Qt5` to `Qt6`.

Comment: In Qt5 case it should also be `console.log(newResult)` as this is the name used in the C++ class

Comment: I use Qt 5.15 and refer to below documentation.   
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html  
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html#details

Comment: Thank you all for replying this question. I think it is solved. The real problem is in yocto build with container image. Code change is not activated until I delete the tmp-container directory then rebuild image. So strictly speaking my code is no problem but just not activated in the new system image. Anyway all the answers and comments are appreciated to let me know more about the connection mechanism in Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Connections with this:

```cpp
        Connections {
            target: MyClass

            onResultChanged: (result) => {
                console.log("onResultChanged triggerred")
                console.log("result: ", result)
            }
        }
```

works for me

Complete example, who is curios to test it. if you will copy that I placed below, I replaced .png with .jpg so be aware of it :)

```
// main.cpp
#include "myclass.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("MyClass", new MyClass());

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
    return 0;
}

// myclass.h
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~MyClass();

    Q_INVOKABLE void monitorResult();

signals:
    void resultChanged(QString newResult);
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H

// myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QDebug>

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::monitorResult()
{
    QString str = "test";

    qDebug() << str;

    emit resultChanged(str);
}

// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: screen
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 93
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    title: qsTr("screen")
    color: "transparent"

    Image {
        id: homeScreen_footer_image
        y: 70
        width: 1920
        height: 93
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        opacity: 1
        source: "qrc:/footer.jpg"

        Timer {
            interval: 250
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: MyClass.monitorResult()
        }

        Connections {
            target: MyClass

            onResultChanged: (result) => {
                console.log("onResultChanged triggerred")
                console.log("result: ", result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did get the str from the onResultChanged function. here is my code:

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~MyClass();
public Q_SLOTS:
    void monitorResult();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void resultChanged(QString newResult);
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::monitorResult()
{
    QString str = "test";

    Q_EMIT resultChanged(str);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("app.MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass");

    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

QML

```
import app.MyClass 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainItm
    MyClass{
        id: myClass
    }
    
    Timer {
        interval: 250
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: myClass.monitorResult()
    }
    
    
    Connections {
        target: myClass
        
        function onResultChanged(result) {
            console.log("onResultChanged triggerred")
            console.log("result: " + result)
        }
    }
}
```